# Connecting Trails in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I am working on mapping trails and reroutes of those trails in West Virginia. I'm going out with a GPS and walking everything and then coming back to the office to project everything on a map(s). The only problem I am having is that some of my trails and reroutes are not connecting at their intersections.

Is there a way to fix this in ArcMap or ArcCatalog so that I don't have to keep driving to the trails and rewalk them (i.e. is there like a spray paint or pencil option).

I've been trying to play around with it for a few days, and it's been a few years since I have had any formal training, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest fixes for this situation is to utilize  [geodatabase topology rules](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01mm0000000m000000).  Specifically, the situation you describe can be identified with the "Must Not Have Dangles" rule.  You can fix these dangles with the [Fix Topology Error tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_fixing_topology_errors/01mm0000000q000000/).

Another option is to use the [Snap (Editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000) tool.

[image]